# Table Catalog is showing as null in SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The view SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS displays ID, Table_NAME,Table_Catalog(Database_Name).

select * from  SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS where  table_catalog is null and deleted='FALSE'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSXWg.png)

How can the Table_Catalog(Database_NAME) column view can be null when these tables are created but I am not able to see these tables as well in the database.

Is there any way I can see the table in snowflake as these objects are not visible at all.

Appreciate your help?

Need help in finding table_catalog as they are all coming as NULL

Answer (score 0):

Note that dropped tables in Fail-safe will potentially display NULL values in most columns. Can it be that you either DROP or REPLACED these tables?
You can check if a table was dropped with something like:
select
start_time,
query_id,
query_text,
user_name
from snowflake.account_usage.query_histroy
where query_text ilike '%DROP TABLE%<TABLE_NAME>%';

In your case:
select
start_time,
query_id,
query_text,
user_name
from snowflake.account_usage.query_histroy
where query_text ilike '%DROP TABLE%MODEL_INFO%';

Comment: Hello Sir, I cannot see the table at all nor I can see anything for the above table?

Comment: Hi, 1. Can it be that the tables you mentioned were dropped? 2. In order to see the snowflake.account_usage.query_histroy you need proper permissions. Are you ACCOUNT_ADMIN?